# How to create a random spawner in unity 2d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am making a game in Unity2D i which you have to match the correct projectiles with the enemies but I can't randomly spawn them, it just spawns one... (btw this is my first game)

````
   {
       timeBTWSpawn = StartTimeBTWSpawn;

       private void Update()
   {

       if(timeBTWSpawn <= 0 )
       {
           rand = Random.Range(0, enemies.Length);
           Instantiate(enemies[0], SpawnPoint.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);```
           timeBTWSpawn = StartTimeBTWSpawn;
       }
       else
       {
           timeBTWSpawn -= Time.deltaTime;
       }
   }
}

i expect 3 different enemies to be randomly spawned but it only spawns the first one in the array.
````

Comment: You should replace the `enemies[0]` with `enemies[rand]` because currently you are instantiating only the first enemy in the array, but if it was `[rand]` then you will be instantiating the enemy at the position returned by the `Random.Range` method

Answer (score 2):

there is one minor mistake. You are not actually using "rand" variable inside the instantiate method. having 0 in the index will always spawn the first element inside enemies array.it should be like this:

**Code:**

```
       Instantiate(enemies[rand], SpawnPoint.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

this will fix :)

Comment: Thanks alot !! I was annoyed by this for so long and I had no idea the problem was this small